# Sharing data between aspects in different assemblies during compile time

Tags: c#, postsharp

I have a custom `TypeLevelAspect` called `PersistentId` which is used on types in several assemblies. I need to store information from these aspects during compile time and use it during runtime - but *before the assemblies are loaded*. Therefore, I was thinking about storing the information in another aspect - in a different assembly which would definitely be loaded.

Is it possible to somehow transfer data during `CompileTimeInitialize` of one aspect to a single instance of another aspect so that it can be stored and retrieved in `RuntimeInitialize` of the second aspect?

EDIT: Sharing data between aspects does seem to work (see the answer below) but only within a single assembly. Is there a mechanism to share it also between different assemblies?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your use case? There's usually a different approach for most use cases.

Comment: I use a custom persistence framework and upon deserialization I need to know the type to construct an instance of (based on a "persistent ID"). So there needs to be some kind of map between a string and the actual type (and assembly) name. I was hoping this can be built dynamically using attributes on each individual type rather than having to manually maintain a huge table in the source code.

Comment: Would it help to automatically generate a managed resource? https://doc.postsharp.net/resource-introduction

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach to share data between aspects using PostSharp Framework is (assuming you want to share a class `MyData`:

- Make sure the `MyData` class is serializable.
- Expose a static public field/property of type `MyData` somewhere.
- In all aspects that need `MyData`, expose an *instance* field of this type, and initialize it to the static instance.

At compile-time, PostSharp will serialize `MyData` in the aspect graph. Because this is a graph, a single instance of `MyData` will be shared among all aspect instances.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this a bit more or point me to the relevation documentation? Where exactly does `MyData` get serialized to? Or more specifically, where can I get the deserialized instance of it from at runtime?

Comment: OK, I get it now - it will be available in `RuntimeInitialize` of the aspect. However, does this also work for aspects across multiple assemblies?

Comment: This would work for the current assembly only. For cross-assembly, you need to add some creativity. You could have some static constructor or a module initializer that populates some shared data structure based on intra-assembly data.